# How to declare group of elements in DTD

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

I declared group of elements in the XML Schema file. How to do the same thing in DTD?

```
<xs:element name="adress">   
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:group ref="adress-group" minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="3"/> 
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:group name="adress-group">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="country" type="country-type"/>
  <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest DTD equivalent to your XSD sample is something like this:

```
<!ENTITY % address-group '(country, city, street)' >
<!ELEMENT address (%address-group;, %address-group;, %address-group;) >
```

I'm not sure of the motivation for requiring that address-group occur exactly three times, but that's another topic.